# User defined range for Excel Solver function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I have searched everywhere and attempted to get this to work correctly for hours but my macro will not play ball and the solver hangs at the 'Setting up problem...' stage!

This is what I am trying to do:
1)User starts macro and is prompted to select a range of cells to optimise
2)Solver finds solution and exits

If anyone might be able to suggest how I might get this to work I would be most grateful!

Many thanks,

Rendeverance

```
This is my code:

Sub Optimise()
Dim UserRange As Range

SolverReset


  Set UserRange = Application.InputBox("Use the mouse to select cells to optimise (Hold       Ctrl to select multiple films)", Type:=8)

    If UserRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cancel pressed"
    Else

    'Set solver parameters and solve using GRG Nonlinear
    '
    SolverOk SetCell:="$V$13", MaxMinVal:="$V$15", ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="UserRange", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: should it be `ByChange:=UserRange.Address,`?

Comment: Hi Simoco - Yes it should sorry. and Thank you! Although now it does not allow me to define a range but only a cell?

Comment: It STILL hangs however, at the same point (I believe due to the MaxMinVal being set to a cell which contains the required value?)

Comment: BTW, `UsedRange` is not good name for variable (because there is `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` propety). I suggest you not to use names that can get you confused

Comment: Thanks again - I shall change that - I do not use VBA much so I am a but sloppy sometimes will fix that. I still have the issue of the hanging however and that when I ask the user to select a range it will not work, it only works where they select an individual cell :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Simoco for identifying the omission of '.Address', but I still could not get the above to work, when defining the MaxMinVal as a cell (instead of just '1' or '2')

So I used a nested IF statement as follows - this works but there may be a more elegant way and if anyone can give me tips on this it would be appreciated:

```
Sub Optimise()

'
Dim OptiRange As Range

' Activate the sheet required and reset solver settings
Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
SolverReset

' Add-in some bad error handling ;-)
On Error GoTo endofmacro

'Ask user for what cells to optimise
Set OptiRange = Application.InputBox("Use the mouse to select cells to optimise (Hold Ctrl to select multiple films individually)", Type:=8)

        'Check if this is a maximise or minimise problem
        If Range("$Z$15").Value = 1 Then
            '
            'Set solver parameters and solve using GRG Nonlinear
            SolverOk SetCell:="$Z$13", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=OptiRange.Address, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
            SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
            SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        Else
            '
            'Set solver parameters and solve using GRG Nonlinear
            SolverOk SetCell:="$Z$13", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=OptiRange.Address, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
            SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
            SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        End If

endofmacro:

End Sub
```